# creating a matrix with a specified name in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can I use string argument input as a variable name in MATLAB? I wanna input a string and use it as the name of a variable

Answer (score 1):

Have the string stored in `str` and the value you want to assign in `val`. You then need to use `eval` in the following manner.

```
eval([str,'= val']);
```

For example,

```
>> str = 'X';
>> val = rand(5);
>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  str       1x1                 2  char                
  val       5x5               200  double              

>> eval([str,'= val'])

X =

    0.8147    0.0975    0.1576    0.1419    0.6557
    0.9058    0.2785    0.9706    0.4218    0.0357
    0.1270    0.5469    0.9572    0.9157    0.8491
    0.9134    0.9575    0.4854    0.7922    0.9340
    0.6324    0.9649    0.8003    0.9595    0.6787

>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  X         5x5               200  double              
  str       1x1                 2  char                
  val       5x5               200  double
```